# Task<T>.Result used to block. Does it still?

Tags: .net

According to the original documentation for `Task<T>.Result`, it caused waiting threads to be blocked.

The prescription was to call `.Wait()` before requesting `.Result`.

Is this still true?  If not, when did it change?

Subsequent question: is calling `.Wait()` before `.Result` (still) helpful or necessary?

EDIT: (more context/detail)

I may have a gross conceptual error here.  But as I understand it...
Calling `.Wait()` will return a task to the scheduler and re-enter once the task is complete.  Effectively the difference between parking your car in the middle of an intersection (blocking everyone) vs stopping on the side of the road until you're ready to move on (while everyone specifically waiting for you also parks on the side).

Mechanisms like Monitor, Semaphore, etc... Will 'block' **all** threads that attempt to gain access to a resource.  Potentially killing your performance unnecessarily.   When I first encountered `.Result` (before async/await) the documentation and supporting information said it was 'blocking'.  Which is likely still true.

What I'm wondering is:

1) Is my understanding of `.Wait()` correct?  Does it give the task back to the scheduler for re-entrance?  It may not have before, but I'm guessing that a compiler optimization could have been implemented to allow this.

2) Is there any real difference between the following:

Just calling `.Result`.

```
var x = task.Result;
```

Or calling `.Wait` before calling `.Result`?

```
task.Wait();
var x = task.Result;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "caused *waiting* threads to be blocked", and do you have a link to said documentation? I could be wrong, but as far as I know `Result` has always blocked until the task is complete, and it has never been necessary to call `Wait()` before accessing `Result`. The current documentation makes this clear: "Accessing [Result] blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method."

Comment: @nlawalker see my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between just calling `Result` and calling `Wait()` followed by `Result`. Both of them rely directly on [Task.InternalWait](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,2a1a81515e799ad9) if the task is not yet completed.

For the first part of your question - `Wait()` does not "return a task to the scheduler and re-enter" later, that's exactly what `await` is for. Waiting blocks the thread it's running on until the task is complete. But it sounds like you are concerned about *mutual exclusion*, as opposed to *blocking*, which is something different.

Blocking means that a thread has executed some code that is causing it to sit and wait for something else to happen. The thread is in use, just as if it was doing real work, but it's sitting doing nothing. This is needlessly wasteful, especially in scenarios like web applications where we always want to have threads available to execute code to handle incoming requests, because threads are effectively a finite resource and there are often ways to wait using OS-level facilities that do not consume a thread (this is essentially what proper use of `async/await` does for you). But blocking does not prevent *other* threads from executing the same code while one thread is inside of it. That is mutual exclusion, which explicitly uses thread synchronization mechanisms like Monitor or Semaphore to limit or prevent concurrent access to a section of code among multiple threads in the same process.

`Result` and `Wait()` are blocking, but do not perform any kind of mutual exclusion.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you for the answer.  What you've said is what I suspected, but wasn't sure.  So to be correct.  Using 'await' is not the same as .Wait()?  Meaning, await actually calls GetAwaiter() and does the scheduling/state-machine magic? Thanks again for the insight.

Comment: Await is *very* different from Wait(), and is indeed the way to take advantage of all the non-blocking magic that the framework does for you. Using Wait() anywhere basically negates all of that and takes you back to simple blocking. As you develop with async/await, you'll notice it becoming very entrenched in your code from the bottom up, such that almost all of your methods return Task or Task<T> - this is not a bad thing, and is effectively how async/await is meant to be used.